# PC Submerged in Mineral Oil: Operating Temps / Warm Environment

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, computer-building, case

I support many PCs in a factory-type environment with very poor air quality.
The air is full of salts and other chemicals that corrode everything and destroy electronics quickly.
I am plagued with PC/hardware failure year-round but especially in the humid spring and summer months.

Earlier this year, I decided to remove the air from the environment by submerging a PC in mineral oil.
It has been running constantly and flawlessly for 3-4 months now.

Under normal load and a room temp of around 24C, it operates with a CPU temp around 45-50C.
Because the enclosure is small, everything in the PC runs at about the same temp.
This is a little high but should not be a problem (at least I don't think so).

In the past couple weeks we have seen high summer outside temps of 35+C and the inside temps are not much slower.  The PC is still performing fine but the overall temps are significantly higher with everything running 60-65C.  While this is technically OK (but not ideal) for a CPU temp, what about everything else.  65C is pretty warm.

I also notice the core/package temps are up in the 70+C.

I am not a trained PC tech as PC support is not my main responsibility and I do not have much experience with temps/cooling.
Is this sustainable?  And are there any components, besides CPU, that I should be concerned with?

My fix is to radiate the mineral oil out side the enclosure (currently a cereal container) but would like to avoid that if possible.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the oil?  Unless you have an air tight container, then the oil after 4 months in a dirty environment, isn’t going to be perstine

Comment: No we haven't changed the oil.  While I wouldn't say that the container is air-tight, it is pretty well sealed. The only part of the container that would possibly see outside air would be where the wires pass through the rubber seal. The container is also inside a cabinet which also keeps blowing dust off of the hardware.  We will need to change the oil at some point but really, if we can get 12 months of use before a failure, we are in net positive territory.

Comment: well, as it stands the oil is a passive cooler, and the component temps track proportionately with ambient temp, so your options are basically to increase oil volume and cycle it around (which is fine for generated heat, but will not scale as the ambient temp rises), or to introduce refrigeration.  you can never cool to less than ambient, and you can't change the heat generation associated with operation, so as the ambient temp increases anything you do becomes more an more marginal. eventually refrigeration becomes the only option.

Comment: Regarding component temperatures, all PC components based around ICs should be able to sustain ~70C, but that is the upper threshold for a lot of consumer hardware and mileage will vary with individual components. Constant excessive heat will degrade electronics faster, but that delta is highly variable. I would have a decent monitoring system setup, so I could be alerted for hardware failures, data integrity issues, and temperature spikes. Something like PRTG can get you started.